# Error in R - cluster.stats

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I am calling DBSCAN from fpc package and trying to validate the cluster results using cluster.stats.

It works perfectly if there are more than one cluster formed. But if only one cluster is formed, then it gives me following error.

Error in sc$clus.avg.widths : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In min(bv) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

My code is,

```
df<-read.table("can3147.txt",header=TRUE,sep="")
dso<-dbscan(df,3,4)
d<-dist(df)
res1<-cluster.stats(d,dso$cluster)
```

the code works perfectly if there is two clusters(either two separate clusters or one cluster and few noise point, which is possible if I take eps value as 0.311).

plz. help me if anyone is knowing how to overcome ?
 or
what other cluster validation pkg can be used for DBSCAN ?

Comment: Could you please give us the dataframe `df`, to make your example reproducible? Or is it too large?

Comment: The maintainer's email address can be obtained with the `maintainer`-function. This sounds worthy of a bug report.

Comment: Sorry, The dataframe is of 3147 rows.